# problems Ubuntu 17.10 and scanner

Tags: drivers, 17.10

I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10 and my scanner (Brother DCP150C) doesn't work anymore.

I installed it again with no problems, but still the message that I get is that the drivers are not installed. I can assure you that driver are installed by running the command `dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother`.

In previous editions of Ubuntu, I had to go, later, to  `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` and add something to this file. Now, I tried to do the same, but I cannot find the `40-libsane.rules` there.

Can anybody please give a a hint on this?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1707352

Answer (score 0):

I installed libsane1 and sane-utils fom artful-proposal.
Then I recognized that "sudo scanimage -L" worked, but "scanimage -L" without sudo did not work. 
So I created /etc/udev/rules.d/55-libsane.rules with the content:

> SYSFS{idVendor}=="04b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

Where "04b8" is the USB id of the scanner manufacturer epson. If you have a brother scanner, you have to replace this id with the one scanimage prints out.

Comment: Thanks JMS. Sorry for having answered only now. I tried that you suggested. My "idVendor" is "04f9". It simply doesn't work. My scanner is never recognized. The printer goes perfectly OK.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane. Read the section on Brother scanners. Once I entered the network configuration it worked.

I used the brscan4 tool on a 64 bit system. The correct driver in my case was brscan4-0.4.4-4.amd64. The page from which I downloaded was:

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=dcpj105_all&os=128

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Carel. I've tried all that. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Complete step-by-step:

http://abhweb.org/jima/brother-scanner-not-recognized-ubuntu-17.10.php

In summary, manually force-install *brscan4* and then run *brsaneconfig4* to register scanners.  *libusb-1.0-0* must also be installed, which it is by default in Ubuntu 17.10

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all brscan4*.deb
sudo brsaneconfig4 -a name=friendlyname model=model ip=static_ip_of_scanner
```

(Older models need brscan or brscan2/3 instead of brscan4)

I recommend using a static IP instead of relying on auto-detect, which still seems flakey.

The problem is that the brscan4 .deb has a dependency on "libusb" but there is no such package in Ubuntu 17.10.  However there is a "libusb-1.0-0" which seems to work.  The name change means that package brscan4 won't install normally, and Brother's "Driver Install Tool" sees the error and doesn't configure a scanner.

Comment: Dear jimav: I tried it but it says there is no  brscan2 file or directory installed. I tried with  brscan,  brscan1,  brscan3 and it was the same. However, yes, there is a "libusb-1.0-0" directory. Thanh you so much for your concern. I think I will wait for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS release and upgrade to it. Then I will try to re-install the scanner and see what happens. But THANKS again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with brother printer/scanner MFC-J625DW.
Could not get the scanner to work until I followed the instructions on this [faq](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc6490cw_all&redirect=on#f00107).  Second item, "I cannot find the brother machine".  Apparently, some files are copied into the wrong folder.  My system is lubuntu 17.10 32-bit and the driver is brscan4.  So also for brscan4 you need this fix. (I have also been editing the 'rules' file , but in the end reverted everything as it did not solve anything.)

According to the faq the fix is :
Check if the following directory exist.

For 64bit Users:
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`

For 32bit Users:
`/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sane`

Type the following command if the above directory exists.

For 64bit Users:
Command : `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`

For 32bit Users:
Command : `sudo cp /usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother* /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sane`

To clarify I will list all actions I did to get my MFC-J625DW to work (reboot between some steps may be useful):

- download, unzip and run script for your device from
  support.brother.com (this installed all necessary packages for my
  device) Follow all instructions on that site.
- add myusername to the
  group lp, owning the scan device `sudo adduser <myusername> lp`
- if you need to find out the name of this group, switch on the device, do
  `lsusb`, note the busnr and devicenr of the brother, and execute `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/busnr/devicenr` (3 digits per nr)
- did the filecopying fix described above
- to enable all features of brscan-skey, I need gimp, sane and xsane
  `sudo apt install gimp`
  `sudo apt install sane sane-utils libsane-extras xsane`